# Django/Python - ImportError: Could not import settings 'twitter.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named settings

Tags: python, django, settings, importerror, python-twitter

I've recently started my first Django project. I have previously been able to run the command 'python manage.py runserver' without returning any errors but now it returns a long error message which I can't solve...

```
 File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 459, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 261, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 69, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.servers.basehttp import AdminMediaHandler, run, WSGIServerException, get_internal_wsgi_application
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 26, in <module>
    from django.views import static
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/static.py", line 95, in <module>
    template_translatable = ugettext_noop(u"Index of %(directory)s")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 75, in gettext_noop
    return _trans.gettext_noop(message)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
    if settings.USE_I18N:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 184, in inner
    self._setup()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 95, in __init__
    raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))
ImportError: Could not import settings 'twitter.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named settings
```

I'm not sure why it's returning this error. The only thing I can think of that might have affected it is that I have recently downloaded and installed the python-twitter library as I'm using the Twitter API in my project. Any help on how to solve this would be very much appreciated!

Thanks,

Jess

Comment: Are you using virtualenv for your environment?

Comment: I'm just working from my localhost at the moment. I'm also using Terminal and SublimeText2 as my text editor.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with the python-twitter library, but my guess is that the module is named `twitter`. So you may be trying to pull in an attribute called "settings" from your python-twitter library. You may want to change your project name.

Comment: Thanks D.A, I think it might be saying twitter.settings because the name of my file is currently 'twitter' until I come up with a name for my project. Do you think that could be why it is saying twitter.settings?

Comment: The name of your project is whatever you put in when you ran the command `django-admin.py runproject <project_name>`. Which, according to the logs, is "twitter". So my guess is that you are conflicting with the module "twitter" that you installed.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. Thank you. I'll change the name of my project to something other than twitter and see if that works. Thank you for your help!